# How to check whether a file is executable or not?

Tags: command-line

I want to check the file is executable or not through the command prompt so that I cannot open the file whether it is executable or not.

Comment: you want to check if a file has the x-flag set?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. First, the question is a different one. But most important, `ls -l` won't help if you want to automate this. Also you need to know if you are the owner, belong to the group or to everyone else. And then it gets really tricky.

Comment: I didn't get any answer required for me

Comment: Then you need to be more specific what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recommended tool to determine a file type is `file`.

Example of an executable file.

```
$ file c.sh a.out
c.sh:  Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
a.out: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=a741679fcc57d5dafa76025d943090fdf614b7e2, not stripped
```

Comment: doesnt give me the needed information: `touch test;` `file test; --> test:empty` `chmod +x test;` `file test --> test: empty `

Comment: You are wrong. From the man pages: `chmod - change file mode bits`. Of course, if you use `chmod +x` you can make an executable. If you test it then you make a circular reasoning. But without changing the file you can determine the file type with the `file` command, or as writen in the man pages: `file — determine file type`.

Comment: What I showed with my example is that output of file is NOT changing after chmod +x ...

Comment: Of course your circular reasoning works perfectly if I use your bash script and line 5 will complete the circular reasoning. If you don't like to read man pages, I just copied the head titles here for you, but you can get fancy information about determining a file type here:  https://www.lifewire.com/file-linux-command-unix-command-4097142

Comment: Who wants to know a file type? Op wants to know if executable. And file doesnt work for that.

Comment: Thats right, the file type tells you the file type and if a file is an executable it will show you that is an executable ;)

Comment: There are no regular files defined in Unix/Linux. But there are a lot of different forms of executable files, like in my code example with different types, there also other executable files and `file`can determine **every** file without a script or other command. Or cant you find the expression `executable` printed by the command `file`?

Comment: I would [prefer `command -v` or `which`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then). E.g. `file /usr/bin/ncdu | grep -i executable` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 11):

**[Bash `test`](https://ss64.com/bash/test.html)**:

`[ -r file ]` tests if a file is readable.
`[ -w file ]` tests if a file is writeable.
`[ -x file ]` tests if a file is executable.

```bash
if [ -x file ]; then
  ./file
else
  echo "File is not executable"
fi
```

Try it with a simple example:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
touch testfile
test -x testfile && echo true || echo false
# --> false
chmod +x testfile
test -x testfile && echo true || echo false
# --> true
rm testfile
```